# Spring -@Recover - Cannot locate recovery method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

I've a Spring project with Retryable and Recover methods inside a class.
After 2 retries, the code is not able to hit the Recover method block and the error is

```
Cannot locate recovery method; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8081/api/start": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The Retryable method is attached to AOP.

The code is available in the Github Repo: https://github.com/Nikhilgupta1891/RetryRecover

Inside the repo, here are the concerned classes names:

1. AOP: ApcAspect.java
2. Scheduler (entry point): ScheduledClass.java
3. Service class not running Recover: ClassTwo.java#L37

Attaching the code of ClassTwo for quick reference:

```
package com.abc.pbm.racassignmentpoll.services;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class ClassTwo {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private final String crimApiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8081/api/";

    @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "2", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "5000"))
    public ResponseEntity startSecondMethod(String invEligDt, String runType) {
        Map<String, Object> reqBody = new HashMap<>();
        reqBody.put("INV_ELIG_DT", invEligDt);
        reqBody.put("RUNTYPE", runType);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(crimApiBaseUrl + "start",
                reqBody,
                null,
                Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        return responseEntity;
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception error, String invEligDt, String runType){
        // Some action.
        log.info("INside recovery");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for reference, if anyone else finds this: This question is a follow-up to the question I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67831919/1082681). The sample repository is also the same.

Answer (score 8):

The return type of both methods and the input parameters for: Retryable and Recovery methods should be same.

Comment: When answering questions, including own ones, please add more detail in order to make it helpful to others. Neither did you post any corrected sample code here for others to learn how to fix the original code, nor did you push a commit fixing the issue to your GitHub repository. To make matters worse, you also committed lots of garbage (binaries, IntelliJ project files), i.e. when inspecting your commits, others "cannot see forest because of too many trees", as we say in German. Please try and give your posts here and also your commits a bit more love in order to make them helpful.